# mysql query for getting count by group and total count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'table1' as follows:

```
col1
----
1      
1
2
2
2
3
3
```

I want to get count by group and total count from this table as follows:

```
col1    group_count   total_count
-------------------------------------
1       2             7
2       3             7
3       2             7
```

I tried as follows:

```
SELECT col1, group_count, total_count FROM 
(SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) AS group_count FROM table1 GROUP BY col1) Temp1, 
(SELECT COUNT(col1) AS total_count FROM table1) Temp2
```

How to do it in optimised way

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show the query you tried?

Comment: You have no PK. Therefore you do *not* have a table!

Comment: To clarify @Strawberry's comment, tables should be an identity column (primary key) in order to make relationships between the tables. Primary Key can also consists of more than 1 column, but seems it is not needed in your case.

Answer (score 6):

the optimized way is to first calculate the count and then simply put the variable in your select statement:

```
set @rowCount = (select count(col1) from table1);
select col1, count(col1), @rowCount from table1 group by col1;
```

[See the result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c605ff/1)

The approach given by @Meherzad will calculate the row count many times. But if you want to do this in a single query u can use:

`select col1, count(col1), (select count(col1) from table1) rowCount 
from table1 group by col1;`

Comment: but I need to get in single query

Comment: how are you using this query?? i mean from java/php etc?? cause you can always put more than one queries in a procedure and u can call that procedure!! 

still if u need that in one query, without cross join or join, you can always go with this.

select col1, count(col1), (select count(col1) from table1) from table1 group by col1;

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select col1, count(*), tot 
from tbl t1, (select count(*) as tot from tbl) t2 
group by col1
```

### [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44c0ae/1)